# Почему комплексные числа включены во встроенные типы, а десятичные - нет?

Tags: python

Почему комплексные числа включены в стандартные типы, а десятичные - нет?

Complex - идет "из коробки", а Decimal - в стандартном (подключаемом) модуле.
В реальной жизни вторые нужны в банковском деле, что намного чаще, чем мнимые числа.

Просто интересен ответ с точки зрения авторов языка.
Кто знает?

Мне кажется логичнее сделать наоборот - а то рассказываешь в школе "встроенные типы" и - тут на тебе такая торпеда...

Должен же был какой-то [PEP (Python Enhancement Proposal)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/) на эту тему сохраниться?

Comment: Десятичные типы есть в стандартной библиотеке. То что они не лежат во встроенной это хорошо - позволяет избежать ошибок когда float умножают на Decimal

Comment: @eri не понял проблемы, такое умножение можно просто запретить

Comment: @andreymal ну значит bool на строку умножать можно, а это запретить?) нет - запрещать не надо.

Comment: ну я вообще молчу что True можно сложить False и получится 1...

Comment: Имхо это тоже стоит запретить :)

Comment: В банковском деле обычно используется фиксированная точка(которая на практике эмулируется целыми числами), а не десятичные числа с FP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я считаю что десятичный тип в стандартных, но не встроенных потому, что он не имеет простого аналога в [c](/questions/tagged/c). Вещественный тип представляется простым типом `complex` в `c99` и не требует постоянного контроля за содержимым при простых операциях. Тип Decimal не реализуется на [c](/questions/tagged/c) даже для простых операций сложения, умножения.

Comment: я говорю о комплексных числах.
`1+3j`. В си ими не пахло

Comment: А ещё тип целых чисел позволяет иметь сколь угодно большие значения, такого в сишечке тоже не было

Comment: @VasylKolomiets а я говорю что они структурой реализуются. любой второкурсник физмата напишет калькулятор на комплексных числах на си.

Comment: @andreymal указатели и malloc никто не отменял)

Comment: @eri это уже не очень похоже на «простой аналог»)

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, вообще говоря, `complex` — часть стандарта со времён c99, хотя в c11 его понизили до опционального расширения.

Comment: @eri - добавь про c99  - я отмечу как ответ.
И - с Новым Годом всех )

Comment: @VasylKolomiets complex был в Питоне *до* c99. Decimal (сейчас) и на Си реализован.

Answer (score 3):

Если верить [HISTORY](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/Misc/HISTORY), то комплексные числа [были добавлены](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f9fca9252f64a93b4598615c504011fa385333ae?diff=unified) в python-1.4-beta1 в 1996-м, что было ещё до PEP'ов, так что на вопрос, почему этот тип встроенный, а не является отдельным модулем доподлинно может ответить только сам Гвидо. Я бы сказал, что только потому, что это позволяет сделать запись вида `1+2j` допустимой.

Тип Decimal был добавлен в python-2.4-alpha-3 в 2004-м (см [PEP-0327](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0327/)). Не вижу ни каких причин, почему он мог бы быть встроенном. Основная причина, почему это не так ИМХО в том, что реализация его достаточно сложна и медленнее в сравнении с двоичной плавающей точкой, а сфера применения, где важно десятичное округление в ущерб скорости крайне мала.

Comment: [python 1.4 выпустили в октябре 1996](https://www.python.org/doc/versions/). Отсутствие  быстрой реализации в то время для Decimal объясняет почему `0.123` создаёт float (дополнительно к лёгкости обмена данными с Си). Как complex так и Decimal константы (literals) редко нужны. Во встроенное пространство имён Decimal также особых причин добавлять нет (также как и complex).

Comment: поправил год+ещё пару огрехов; 1997-й вылез из blame'а HISTORY.